# Site faster on 1 core/1GB ram than on 8 core/32GB ram wth?

Tags: vps, website, loading

Both sites are US based.
I'm located in Europe.

```
http://198.105.209.13/ <==== site that loads tons faster on 1 core and 1gb ram ONLY (Cent OS VPS)

http://108.61.35.219/ <== site is located on my dedicated server with i7-3770 cpu and 32 gb ram (Windows) and is slow as hell
```

Even if faster site is on linux it shouldn't make such a big difference in page load seriously. Does anyone know what could be a hiccup on the dedicated server? It's just unbelievable to me that site loads faster on 1 core cpu than on dedicated server.

Note that site is pretty much only thing running on dedicated server. It has 1gbps connection.

Comment: what os level on the windows server? Both doing apache stuff?  And are you able to change things without interrupting important things?

Comment: Dedicated server is on windows 7, the previous server I had (On different location) had windows also and the loading time was lightning fast. What are you aiming at with And are you able to change things without interrupting important things?"? Both VPS and Dedi are using nginx.

Comment: Did you attempt to hit F12 in Chrome, use the Firefox Web Developer extension, YSlow, Google Page Speed, or _anything at all_ before coming here?

Comment: well if it had been a server version of the os I'd have you park the cpu's down to just 1 to see if its a threading issue, but thats a real stretch.

Comment: along with @MichaelHampton if tesing within ie7+ fiddler will give you the details also.

Answer (score 12):

I just hit F12 in Google Chrome and loaded up your sites. This is what I learned:

Your dedicated server *is* much faster than your VPS. It returned all of its resources almost twice as fast as the VPS. The problem with your slow speed doesn't lie there.

The problem is this:

You are loading some of your resources from www.elitereviewing.com, which loads fast, and a few of your resources from elitereviewing.com, which is occasionally slow. Unfortunately these are two completely different sites, and for some reason, occasionally the DNS lookup for elitereviewing.com is taking exactly five seconds to complete.

Worse, it appears the TTL on your DNS records is 30 seconds, so this is happening *very frequently*.

The problem, then, is not with the web servers, but with the DNS servers. It's time to look into why some of your DNS requests take five seconds to return a response. Since it appears your DNS is hosted with CloudFlare, you should take the matter up with them.

Comment: 5s is the default dns timeout, though this would suggest a local dns problem (and maybe not the exact same behaviour to the OP). Perhaps his very low ttl is triggering some rate limiting?